# SwiftUI pass data from UIViewRepresentable to SwiftUI's View

Tags: swiftui

I am writing a custom scrollview to enable image zooming and positioning. Since it will be used in a SwiftUI View, I conform to `UIViewRepresentable`. I am trying to get the `zoomScale` property as well as the `contentOffset` of the scroll view in order to determine exactly how the image looks like (currently zoomed and positioned). Usually this will be 1.0 and (0,0) if the image is not zoomed nor positioned differently.

The issue I am facing is that if I pass bindings into the view that change when the zoom scale changes or when the contentOffset changes, then the view is redrawn (as the backing @State is refreshed). This leads to problems such as "Updating state while view is updating" error.

As well as the contentOffset and zoom scale being reset as `makeUIView` is called again. If I reuse the values there too, we almost get into a loop of events.

`Scale changes -> Binding changes -> State changes -> Redraw UI -> Scale changes ...`

Is there any way to pass data out of a view without making it refresh when that data changes in SwiftUI? What about ViewPreferences? Could they work?

Another problem occurs when any other unrelated @State changes in the "superview", the scale and contentOffset are reset, so I kind of need to pass a binding into that view.

Thanks

Comment: It sounds as there are bugs in your code, because `makeUIView` should not be called when binding of representable changed, only `updateUIView`, so would you provide your code?

Answer (score 0):

One method I have found was to add a "shouldUpdateState" boolean to your coordinator.

When the scale changes, set shouldUpdateState to false.

Then set your binding.

The first line of your updateUIView method should be

```
guard context.coordinator.shouldUpdateState else {
    context.coordinator.shouldUpdateState = true
    return
}
```

Its sort of a hacky solution... Unfortunately there does not seem to be any good way of managing this.

Another alternative that might work ( I have not tested it) is to use an observable object like so.

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var zoomScale: CGFloat
}
```

and inside your UIViewRepresentable

```
// Note we aren't using @ObservedObject here. 
// It shouldn't trigger view reloads when you update your viewModel. 
// But it will still trigger them in your swiftUI views.
var viewModel: ObservableObject<ViewModel>

init(viewModel: ObservableObject<ViewModel>) {
    self._viewModel = viewModel
}
```